# multimeter, current measurement (beginner)

Tags: current-measurement, multimeter

From this little circuit I try to calculate the current for **Ic, Ib, Ie**.

For **Ic** , I put the multimeter on 20mA and positive wire connected to 10A and I got 0.01 ... 10mA ? for **Ie** it is the same (**Ie** = **Ic** + **Ib** ? really)
For **Ib** I have no value with the same previous multimeter config. I also try to switch on 20uA, 200uA etc... but no value and I have also try to connect positive wire on VΩmA , but no value again. What did I not understand in using a multimeter please? Thank you.

[image]

For **Ib** I try :

[image: For Ib I try :]

Comment: It didn't take 60 seconds to google for "dt830b manual" and get https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5939e22ac534a5226114de77/t/59b89b43d2b85706ab869522/1505270605630/DT830B-Instruction-Manual.pdf which shows how to do what you're asking.

Comment: I have already looked at the manual. but maybe I did not understand well then!

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat,  Finally I think understand after re-reading the manual. but this not resolve my problem.Thanks anyway.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat, yes this is my last test, as I specified, I also try to switch on 20uA, 200uA etc... but no value and I have also try to connect positive wire on VΩmA , but no value again.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat, thank you, I found 1.04V for Ur , 1.04/55 = 0.019 A , i switch on 20 mA , I connect positive wire on V/Ω/mA ... but no luck, nothing. LED don't bright up when wire is connected to V/Ω/mA.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat, thank you again. I have put the multimeter between my 55Ω and my LED, switch multmeter on 200mA and wire on V/Ω/mA . No light, no current. That means that the fuse is burnt if I understand correctly ? (sorry English is not my native language)

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat , Yes this is my case as a beginner, yet I am rather the type to think carefully before acting ... but it is enough of a fault. I thank you for your time now it remains for me to know if I can change this fuse. Thanks again.

Comment: @ Yes , thank you.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat, effectively I see that clearly 250mA burned fuse. Thank you again for all. How I can validate a response for my question on stackexchange when my answer is in comment ?

Answer (score 1):

My problem is that the 250mA fuse of the DT-830B is **burned**. I managed to solve the problem following the recommendations of @StainlessSteelRat

Answer (score 0):

If you have the positive meter lead in the 10A socket, the meter switch MUST be set to the 10A position to get a valid reading.  If the switch is set to any other position, the readings are (probably) meaningless.

To measure current, the meter must be inserted in the circuit, so all the current to be measured will flow through it.  You sketch shows the meter properly connected to measure base current.

Comment: Thank you, I put the switch on 10A and I find also the same values ​​for Ic and Ie but for Ib nothing happens unfortunately.

Comment: @Ephemeral In all likelihood, the base current is too low for the 10A range to measure.

Comment: @Hearth, thank you but , as I specified, I also try to switch on 20uA, 200uA etc... but no value and I have also try to connect positive wire on VΩmA , but no value again.